# sympyで、円周率(piとmath.pi)の使い方の違いを教えて下さい。

Tags: sympy, 数学

①計算1と計算2の使い方の違いを教えて下さい。
②キーインを少なくしたいので、piだけでできると助かります。
③(追加)ルートの正解は、sympyで、できるはず?

sympyで入試問題に挑戦！
解説は、理解できてません。方べきの定理ですか?

(参考)入試問題に挑戦！ 平成17年宮城県(超難)
http://www.5kaku.net/?p=9299
(参考)WolframAlphaで
28/3 π - 3 sqrt(3)
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=28%2F3+%C3%97+%CF%80+%E2%80%93+3%E2%88%9A3+&lang=ja

```
import math
from sympy import *
def my_sanArea(a,b,deg):
    return 1/2*a*b*sin(deg*math.pi/180)
def my_yumArea(r,deg):
    return 1/2*r**2*(deg*math.pi/180-sin(deg*math.pi/180))
g=8.0
L=2.0
# t=(180-60)*pi/180      #計算1
t=(180-60)*math.pi/180   #計算2
#
P0= Point(0.0, 0.0)
P1= P0+Point(-g/2, 0.0)
P2= P0+Point( g/2, 0.0)
P3= P0+Point(L*cos(t), L*sin(t))
C123 = Circle(P1, P2, P3)
P0P2 = P0.distance(P2)
P1P3 = P1.distance(P3)
AS1 = my_sanArea(g/2,L,60.0)
AR1 = my_yumArea(C123.radius,math.asin(P1P3/2/C123.radius)*180/math.pi*2)
#
result = C123.intersection(Line(P3, P0))
PK = Point(result[1][0], result[1][1])
P0PK = P0.distance(PK)
P2PK = P2.distance(PK)
AS2 = my_sanArea(P0P2,P0PK,60.0)
AR2 = my_yumArea(C123.radius,math.asin(P2PK/2/C123.radius)*180/math.pi*2)
#
print('面積=',AS1+AR1+AS2+AR2)
print('面積=',float(AS1+AR1+AS2+AR2))

# 正解            28/3 × π – 3√3 c㎡
# wolfram   面積= 24.125379010798105011735665886091076485011831966069845778265395256...
# AutoCAD   面積= 2412.53790108　ｍｍ2
#
# 計算1の結果 面積= 24.1253790107981
# 計算1の結果 面積= 24.125379010798106
# 計算2の結果 面積= 10.2689725502471 + 5.54256258422039e-13*sqrt(625000000000001464921241321)
# 計算2の結果 面積= 24.12537901079808
```

Comment: 実際に試した結果はどうなりましたか？ / Python は詳しくありませんが、import 宣言の違いがポイントじゃないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pi` は `from sympy import *` でインポートされたもので、元々は `sympy.pi` です。円周率を表します。 https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=pi#pi

`math.pi` は Python の標準ライブラリの math モジュールで定義されている定数です。円周率を利用可能な精度の浮動小数点数で表します。 https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/math.html#math.pi

①計算1は `sympy.pi` に関して記号計算を行うので、正確に(2/3)πを表します。計算2は精度に限りのある浮動小数点数計算なので、(2/3)πの近似値になります。手元の環境では2.0943951023931953でした。

②何を計算したいかによります。片方の `pi` だけ使うならそちらだけ from-import でインポートしてください。両方とも使うなら from-import-as で短い別名をつけることもできます。

```py
import math
from sympy import *
from math import pi as mpi

t=(180-60)*pi/180      # 計算1
t=(180-60)*math.pi/180 # 計算2
t=(180-60)*mpi/180     # 計算2′
```